# uninitialized constant ApplicationRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, localhost, railstutorial.org

I am working on the rails tutorial book online and I am getting the following error message when I go to http://localhost:3000/

> "uninitialized constant ApplicationRecord"

and it gives me the following code highlighting the first line.

```html
class User < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :remember_token
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
```

Here is my application.html.erb file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all",
                                           "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
      <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
        <div class="alert alert-<%= message_type %>"><%= message %></div>
      <% end %>
      <%= yield %>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
      <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my user.rb file :

```html
class User < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :remember_token
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }

  # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                  BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end

  # Returns a random token.
  def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  # Remembers a user in the database for use in persistent sessions.
  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
  end

  # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
  def authenticated?(remember_token)
    return false if remember_digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
  end

  # Forgets a user.
  def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
  end
end
```

Comment: could you check the presence of `app/models/application_record.rb`?

Comment: I don't have an application_record.rb file, should I have one?

Comment: Application Record is only for rails 5. Are you running rals 5?

Comment: No, im not running rails 5, im runing rails 4.

Comment: that was the problem I was running rails 4

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It appears you're using the Rails 5 tutorial, but working with Rails 4. In Rails 5 all models inherit from `ApplicationRecord`, while Rails 4 from `ActiveRecord::Base`

Immediate fix:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
...
end
```

Long term fix, switch to Rails 5 and learn with Rails 5

Answer (score 24):

Referring to infused's answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/41388844/5598043

Create a new file called `app/models/application_record.rb` with the following content:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are getting this after moving from Rails 5 to Rails 6, ensure you change

```
config.load_defaults 5.2
```

for

```
config.load_defaults 6.0
```

in your `config/application.rb` file.